# Can not install OAuth2 Authentication odoo12

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I have a problem with installing OAuth2 Authentication in odoo 12.

Error:

```
Element '<xpath expr="//div[hasclass('o_login_auth')]">' cannot be located in parent view
```

How can I fix this? And how do I show the google login button on login view?

Comment: Element '<xpath expr="//div[hasclass('o_login_auth')]">' cannot be located in parent view

Answer (score 0):

Have you made changes to your web.login view in Odoo? If you have modified it yourself or by installing modules that modify it, you could be missing the `<div class="o_login_auth"/>` element. This would result in the error you described.

The Google login button will be visible when you set Allowed = True for the "Google OAuth2" provider in the "OAuth Providers". You can find this setting in Odoo menu `Settings / Users & Companies / OAuth Providers`. You can find more information about Google OAuth2 login from Odoo documentation at https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/12.0/general/auth/google.html.

I hope these help you forward. Please update your question and include more detailed information if you request more help from Stack Overflow community.